# 2D Open Street Map Data Representation in Meters

Tags: gis, postgis, minecraft, openstreetmap

I am in the process of converting OSM data into an open source Minecraft port (written in javascript - [voxel.js](http://voxeljs.com)). The javascript rendition is written such that each voxel (arbitrarily defined as a cubic meter) is created as a relation from a single point of origin (x,y,z)(0,0,0).

As an example, if one wanted to create a cubic chunk of voxels, one would simply generate voxels as a relation to the origin (0,0,0) : [(0,0,0),(1,0,0), (0,1,0)...].

My question is this: I've exported OSM data, and the standard XML output (.osm) plots nodes in latitude and longitude. My initial thought is that I can create a map by calculating the distance of each node from an arbitrary point of origin (0,0,0) = (37.77559, -122.41392) using the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), convert the distance to meters, find the bearing, and plot it as a relation to (0,0,0).

I've noticed, however, that there are a number of other export formats available: (.osm.pbf, .osm2pgsql, .imposm). I'm assuming they plot nodes in a similar fashion (lat, lng), but some of them have the ability to import directly into a database (e.g. PostgreSQL).

I've heard of people using PG add-ons like PostGIS, but (as this is my first dive into GIS) I'm unfamiliar with their capabilities and whether something *like* PostGIS would help me in plotting OSM data into a 2D voxel grid.

Are there functions within add-ons like PostGIS that would enable me to dynamically calculate the distance between two Lat/Lng points, and plot them in an x,y fashion?

I guess, fundamentally, my question is: if I create a script that plots OSM data into an x,y grid would I be reinventing the wheel, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform from the spherical coordinates (LatLon, using WGS84) to cartesian coordinates, like googles spherical mercator.

In pseudo code

```
    transform(double lat, double lon) {

double wgs84radius = 6378137;
double shift = PI * wgs84radius;
double x = lon * shift / 180;
double y = log(tan((90+lat)*PI/360)/ (PI/180);
return {x,y}
}
```

This is the simplest way. Keep in mind that Lat/Lon are angles, while x and y are distances from (0/0)

Answer (score 1):

The OSM data is by default in the WGS84 (EPSG:4326) projection which is based on an ellipsoidal Earth and measures latitude and longitude in degrees.

Most map tiles are generated in the EPSG:900913 "Google" spherical mercator projection.  This projection is based on a spherical Earth and latitude and longitude are measured in metres from the origin.

It really seems like the 900913 projection will fit quite nicely with your requirements.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/871897) is some code for converting between the two.

You might like to consider using [osm2psql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql). During the import process all of the OSM  map data is converted to the 900913 projection.  What you are left with is a database of all the nodes, lines and polygons of the OSM map data in an easy to access Postgres database.

I was initially intimidated by this process but it is really quite straightforward and will give you lots of flexibility when it comes to using the OSM data.