# What is the projection in the database which is made by osm2pgsql?

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude, openstreetmap

I want to search in the database made by osm2pgsql to render map tiles. I found this table which saved the lat and long for nodes. But these numbers don't seem to be in degree system or degree minutes seconds.
This is result of a query to find Tehran. (The true values for this city are lat="35.6884243" lon="51.4179604" but fetched values are lat="426776659" and lon="573163530")

```
    id            lat          lon            tags
----------------------------------------------------------
 600129599     426776659     573163530       (Null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projection that is being used is EPSG:900913. This is a spherical mercator projection and its units are in metres.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/871897) is some code to do the conversion to decimal degrees.

You should also look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34276/whats-the-difference-between-epsg4326-and-epsg900913) for a discussion about the common projections used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14814664/1809671 see here how to conver latlon to epsg:900913